# Monthly wise data show issues in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to show the data in my database on a monthly basis. Since I have two data for the month of May in my database, now I want to see all the data for the month of May as soon as I click in May, so I used this query:

```
public function RentCertificate(){
    $report = Report::select('reports.*',DB::raw("MONTHNAME(created_at) as monthname"))
        ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
        ->groupBy('monthname')
        ->get();
    return view('adcr.report.rent_certificate', compact('report'));
}
```

And I used this query to show specific month data:

```
public function ViewRentCertificate($id)
{
    $report = Report::where('month', $id)->get()->groupBy('month');
    dd($report);
}
```

But when I write this query, my data comes of an array. This is the output:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1424 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "May" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1417 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => App\Models\Basic\Report {#1433 ▶}
        1 => App\Models\Basic\Report {#1434 ▶}
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

When I used this query to show data in my view:

```
    public function ViewRentCertificate($id)
    {
        $report = Report::where('month', $id)->get()->groupBy('month');
            return view('adcr.report.modal.rent_modal', compact('report'));
    }
```

I got Property [fiscal_year] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\wamp64\www\report-management\resources\views\adcr\report\modal\rent_modal.blade.php)

How can I access this data?

This is my view:

```
@foreach($report as $row)
    <td>{{$row->fiscal_year}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is the fourth time you've asked for assistance on showing monthly data. I wonder if you need more help than you are likely to get from volunteers. Can you reach out to a colleague, or get a freelancer to give you some steering?